# Transpose unevenly-sized lists

Tags: scala, list

I'm having some trouble transposing lists with uneven amounts of elements. Let's say our data is:

```
ABC
E
GHI
```

I want my list to be:

```
List(List('A','E','G'), List('B',' ','H'), List('C',' ','I'))
```

I cannot manage to get empty spaces (`' '`) where I need them. With my code:

```
val l = List("ABC", "E", "GHI")
println(((l map (_.toArray)) toArray).transpose map (_.toList) toList)
// I get: List(List('A', 'E', 'G'), List('B', 'H'), List('C', 'I'))
```

A solution may be to get the longest line and add white spaces to the rest of the lines, but it's really not clean. Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a code-golf solution for an input list `l`:

```
(0 until l.map(_.size).max).map(i => l.map(s => Try(s(i)).getOrElse(' ')))
```

which returns:

```
 Vector(List(A, E, G), List(B,  , H), List(C,  , I))
```

This:

- Retrieves the maximum length of a string in the input list.
- Loop from 0 until the max length of a string in the input list
- Within each loop it gets each element's char at the given index.

The `Try` is used to handle items whose length is shorter than the current index being handled. And these cases return `" "` instead.

To use `Try`, you need to import:

```
import scala.util.Try
```

Comment: Your return type is `Seq[List[Any]]` because you're mixing `Char` elements with a `String` OrElse. Also, `Try` not needed: `_.toSeq.lift(i).getOrElse(' ')`

Comment: I do like your `lift` suggestion indeed.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use [`padTo`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#padTo(len:Int,elem:A):List[A]), although this will involve multiple traversals of the list:

```
val l = List("ABC", "E", "GHI")
val maxSize = l.map(_.size).max // 3
val transposed = l.map(_.toList).map(_.padTo(maxSize, ' ')).transpose
// List[List[Char]] = List(List(A, E, G), List(B,  , H), List(C,  , I))
```